# The [ghost-blog] is ghosting [ghost]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Back in 2013 I asked a question about [ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost). That tag was [subsequently removed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19814163/revisions) and replaced with [ghost-blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost-blog), a tag with 271 questions. It seems that in 2015 the [ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost) tag was recreated, and since then it has attracted 195 questions.

### [ghost-blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost-blog)

> Ghost is a minimalistic open source blogging platform that is built with JavaScript (Node.js in particular) and that defaults to Markdown for drafting posts.

### [ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost)

> Ghost is a simple blogging platform. It is based on node.js and Express on the server side, SQLite3 or MySQL as a database, and Handlebars on the client side. Its source code is hosted on https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost

Where I only have reputation in [ghost-blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost-blog) I'm unable to request that as a synonym of [ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost).

Who am I gonna call?

[image: Ghostbusters!]

Comment: IMO `[ghost]` is terribly ambiguous and likely [to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42181971) [be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34207495) [misused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39853413). I would vote for it to be burninated rather than synonymized.

Comment: @Siguza Urge to k̶i̶l̶l̶ edit those questions and remove the unnecessary tag rising.

Comment: Meh, @Siguza those are all normal. The best one is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246980/is-there-something-following-me). ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi8Vt.png))

Comment: @BhargavRao Wow, mods see a _lot_ more links.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Nah, that's because of a userscript. We see only one additional link. All those options comeup when you click that link (similar to the close vote dialog). The US makes things easier by adding those as one click links.

Comment: "It seems that in 2015 the ghost tag was recreated" -- Alternative title: "[ghost] came back from the dead?"

Comment: There are ~300 questions under both tags now. It makes it very hard to help people here on SO. Can we get them merged one way or another?

"ghost" would be preferred as it is a trademark

Comment: @ErisDS, I have done it the opposite way in order to prevent users from adding the tag for other generic usages of [ghost].

Answer (score 5):

Finally after an year and three months, we've managed to call the exorcist, and removed the tag [ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost).

[ghost-blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost-blog) had 312 questions and [ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost) had 257 questions, and were both being used to talk about the same blogging platform.

I have synonymized [ghost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost) -> [ghost-blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghost-blog) (and not the opposite way), in order to prevent questions like:

- [Is there something following me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246980/4099593) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi8Vt.png))
- [How to catch notorious ghosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36777743/4099593) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxt2T.png))